# .wav file url not playing in Android oreo and pie devices

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer= new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
  mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://52.14.114.148/uploads/user_uploads/6zcbiwjp17o4.wav");
  mediaPlayer.prepare(); 
  mediaPlayer.start();
```

> Here I call the media player which play the audio in below version of oreo 
>   .This is not working in oreo and pie android.

Comment: I was able to play this without any problem. Did you add the INTERNET permission to the Manifest?

Comment: yes already added. but not working in the orio and pie android version. I check on Realme and Nokia 6.1 device.